# Adding plots from large data files

Tags: pgfplots, files

I have the following "stardard file" for plotting data files from simulation results:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \begin{axis}[
    title=Effect of filter,
    minor x tick num =1,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    anchor=origin,
    grid,
    xlabel = $ time $ \lbrack \space s \rbrack, 
    ylabel = $volt$, 
    ytick={0, 200, ...,1000}]

        \addplot [black,very thick] table [x={time}, y={V(pwm)}] {ltspice2.txt};
        \addlegendentry{Source Voltage}

        \addplot [red,thick] table [x={time}, y={V(n002)}] {ltspice1.txt};
        \addlegendentry{Terminal Voltage}

    legend pos = north east,
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that some of the data files are  very large. The latest one contains over 100k lines.

Is it possible to make LaTeX only read e.g. every tenth line?

As of now I get an error saying "tex capacity exceeded" when trying to build the whole data file.

Comment: It will likely be easier to use `awk` or your favorite scripting language to put every 10th line into a new file. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18352241) seems like a good way to do that.

Comment: The problem with every 10th value approach is that it is a not an efficient method and you could change the look of your plot (e.g. if the peak of a spike happens to be a non-10th value). You need intelligent data reduction. Are you by any chance using Matlab for your simulation - if so try this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40790-plot--big- (that link explains the principle too)

Comment: I would agree with @AubreyBlumsohn -- but only if your timeseries is unsmooth, i.e. if it actually contains very small spikes. If the plot is smooth, you may safely omit 9 of 10 points. You could use the builtin key `each nth point=10` and see how much your plot changes (and if it helps your memory issues). Note that `lualatex` is better at memory management.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely pre-process the data file if you have 100,000 points and plot a trimmed data file.

Eliminating every 10th point is not efficient and you risk eliminating spikes, despite still having 10,000 points.

The below is a sample Excel spreadsheet (in xml format that should load into recent versions of excel) that shows one possible crude but more intelligent data trimming method. The idea is to imagine that the data is being plotted at a certain realistic pixel size e.g. X scale over 1000 pixels and Y over 500 pixels. If the next data point is the same pixel as the last data point, then it serves no point in the plot and might as well be rejected. The spreadsheet just shows the concept.

Clearly there are other intelligent methods (all data is on a line, you might as well eliminate intervening points etc). But certainly if you are repeatedly hitting the same pixel, you are redundant.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Aubrey Blumsohn</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Aubrey Blumsohn</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2015-11-15T23:58:16Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2015-11-16T00:09:28Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>15.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>12135</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>25200</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="15" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Xmin</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Xmax</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1000</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Ymin</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">200</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Ymax</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">600</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PixelsX</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1000</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PixelsY</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">500</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Index="8">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Data</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">X</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Y</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PixelX</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PixelY</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Eval</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">222</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">250</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300.60000000000002</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400.2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">223</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">250</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">&lt; Reject all data points with a 1 as they would be on the same pixel at chosen scale</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300.39999999999998</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400.1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">223</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">250</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300.3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400.1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">223</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">250</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">301</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400.5</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">223</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">251</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">300.60000000000002</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">400.7</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R5C2*(RC[-2]-R1C2)/(R2C2-R1C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">223</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=ROUND(R6C2*(RC[-2]-R3C2)/(R4C2-R3C2),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">251</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],IF(R[-1]C[-1]=RC[-1],1,0),0)"><Data
      ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>9</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>4</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```